# what is difference @RequestMapping(value="/abc") and @RequestMapping(value="abc")

Tags: spring, request-mapping

I've a question

Is there difference @RequestMapping(value="/abc") and @RequestMapping(value="abc") ??

In my spring project, they are running a little difference. Actually not a little.

could you tell me the difference?

Comment: @user85421 I misunderstood your answer. I accepted your comment and Alexander's also.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but i haven't seen any difference when changed my controllers code.  But it's a better  practice to write `@RequestMapping("/this")` instead of `@RequestMapping("this")`, because it's better seen. I hope it helps.